# keras seems not using my custom designed loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I defined a triplet loss function as follow:

```py
def triplet_loss(self, alpha):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        anc, pos, neg = (
            y_pred[:, :emb_size],
            y_pred[:, emb_size : 2 * emb_size],
            y_pred[:, 2 * emb_size :],
        )
        distance1 = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(anc - pos, 2), 1, keepdims=True))
        distance2 = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(anc - neg, 2), 1, keepdims=True))
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(distance1 - distance2 + alpha, 0.0))
    return loss
```

and then I compile it with my model:

```py
optimizer = SGD(
    lr=self.learning_rate,
    # lr_multipliers=learning_rate_multipliers,
    momentum=0.5,
)

self.model.compile(
    loss=self.triplet_loss(
        alpha=margin,
        # emb_dim=emb_size
    ),
    optimizer=optimizer,
)
```

then the model start training process by using `self.model.train_on_batch(data)`,

> Iteration 1/10000: Train loss: 4.558698, lr = 0.001000
> Iteration 2/10000: Train loss: 4.558681, lr = 0.001000
> Iteration 3/10000: Train loss: 4.558654, lr = 0.001000
> Iteration 4/10000: Train loss: 4.558623, lr = 0.001000

However, the problem is that I didn't even pass the `emb_size`  to the loss function. And I tried to remove the every thing in my function`loss` in my loss function as:

```py
def triplet_loss(self, alpha):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        print("My loss function")

    return loss
```

and run the training program again, the training can still working:

> Iteration 1/10000: Train loss: 4.556189, lr = 0.001000
> Iteration 2/10000: Train loss: 4.556171, lr = 0.001000
> Iteration 3/10000: Train loss: 4.556145, lr = 0.001000

So I think the keras is not using my loss function at all, why would this happen? What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This entire code can be find here: https://github.com/Colin-Guolin/Oneshot-Learning/blob/main/SiameseNetworkWithTripletLoss.py

Comment: It is probably because in your imports you are mixing keras and tf.keras imports and that is not supported and produces very strange behavior.

Comment: I have tried changing the import to `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer,Concatenate,Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense, Input, Subtract, Lambda,MaxPooling2D,concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
` but the problem still exists, the model seems not using my loss function

Comment: Those are not all the relevant imports.

Comment: I have changed all the relevant imports to tensorflow.keras.***